# c++ new and delete pointer in two files

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

I have a confused for a long while.

let's say, I have two files: file1 and file2, where file1 has Class A and file2 has Class B

file1.h:

```
Class B;
Class A
{
   public:
   vector<B *> myvec1;
   vector<B *> myvec2;
   void useBptr();
   ~A();
};
```

file2.h:

```
#include "A.h"
Class B 
{

    void createPointer1();
    B * createPointer2();
    void wraperCreatePointer2();
    void dummyUse();
    ~B();
}
```

file2.ccp

```
void B::createPointer1(vector<B*> & myvec1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        B * myptr = new B();
        myvec1.push_back(myptr);
    }
}

void B::wraperCreatePointer2(vector<B*> & myvec2)
{
     for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
     {
         myvec2.push_back(createPointer2());
     }
}
```

file1.cpp

```
void A::useBptr()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myvec1[i]->dummyUse();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myvec2[i]->dummyUse();
    }
}

A::~A()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        delete myvec1[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        delete myvec2[i];
    }
}
```

Question is: does my way of delete pointer is correct? will it cause any memory leak? What is the correct way to delete pointer which created like the above code?

The reason I have this question is that I suppose If I created(new the pointer) in the class B, then I need to delete it in the class B.

Comment: Better use a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>` and don't care.

Comment: It doesn't matter which class creates and deletes the pointers. All that matters is that all pointers that were created should be deleted.

Comment: Where is the definition of `createPointer2()`?

Comment: For my createPointer2(), my purpose is just want to it return a pointer. and then store it in the myvec2.

Comment: @Barmar So how about the way which I delete the pointer? Does that correct?

Comment: Use smart pointers! Raw `new` and `delete` are invitations to leak memory.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand smart pointer , but what I care is the way dealing with pointer by myself.

Comment: @Teddy _"but what I care is the way dealing with pointer by myself"_ **Just don't do it**, unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: @erip the year 2015 trends in C++ Core Guidelines (and in Bjarne's talk on cppcon'15) lead us to the opposite: use raw pointers and owner semantics actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as every pointer that's allocated is also deleted (and only deleted once), it doesn't matter which class does it. There's no memory leak in your code.

To make the design easier to understand, and make it more maintainable, it's a good idea to do the deletions in the same class as the creations. This way, if you change the way you allocate the pointers, you don't have to modify all the callers, you just update the corresponding deletion code in the same class.